How to override _id in mongoose
I have a schema like this:
const sessionCardSchema = new Schema(
    {
        unit: Number,
        creator: String
    }
);

I can save a card like this:
const Card = {
  unit: 2,
  creator: 'Jack'
}
const sessionCard = new db.SessionCard(Card);
await sessionCardModel.save(); 

The issue is I cannot save my own objectId as _id of the document.
Here is what I tried:
My schema:
Note: with or without _id in the schema it doesn't work.
const sessionCardSchema = new Schema(
    {
        
        // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        unit: Number,
        creator: String

    }, { _id: false }
);

My code:
const Card = {
  _id: '657c95a4b6e31b1c968aec94'
  unit: 2,
  creator: 'Jack'
}
const sessionCard = new db.SessionCard(Card);
await sessionCardModel.save(); 


Define "doesn't work".  You are setting type ObjectId, but assigning a string.

Exactly as @AlexBlex mentioned, the _id should be of type ObjectId.
Try the following:
const Card = {
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('657c95a4b6e31b1c968aec94'),
  unit: 2,
  creator: 'Jack'
};
